# Angular StackOverflow Activity, a module for showing off your public activity

Tags: app, javascript

### Screenshot

[image]

### About

[AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) directive module for showing off your public StackOverflow activity. Works well with responsive frameworks including [Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/). Customizable templates and iconography.

### Source

https://github.com/gigablox/angular-stackoverflow-activity/

### Homepage

http://gigablox.github.io/angular-stackoverflow-activity